# How to use a previous generated value in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Given this:

```
import datetime as dt

start_date = dt.date(2018,6,28)
steps_back = 4
```

Is there a way to implement the following using list comprehension in python ?

```
a_list = [start_date]

for i in range(1,steps_back):
    a_list.append(a_list[i-1] - dt.timedelta(7))
```

The result would look like this:

```
[datetime.date(2018, 6, 28),
 datetime.date(2018, 6, 21),
 datetime.date(2018, 6, 14),
 datetime.date(2018, 6, 7)]
```

where would you indicate the start value ?

Comment: You can't use the previous value in a list comprehension. You *could* do `[start_date - dt.timedelta(i * 7) for i in range(steps_back)]`, which recreates the first element but is otherwise relatively efficient.

Comment: Or `[start_date - dt.timedelta(i * 7) if i else start_date for i in range(steps_back)]`, which is slightly more efficient but arguably less easy to understand.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: why is your second solution is more efficient?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov because it doesn't rebuild the `start_date` to be the first element in the table, it uses the existing object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: but it checks other `i` for "non-zeroness"

Comment: @AzatIbrakov well you could profile/time it if efficiency is really important, but an integer comparison is pretty well optimised.